# Swift stop CABasicAnimation

Tags: swift, animation, cabasicanimation

Im used CABasicAnimation for animate view like pulse frame

Have code

```
extension UIView {
/// animate the border width
func animateBorderWidth(toValue: CGFloat, duration: Double) -> CABasicAnimation {
    let widthAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderWidth")
    widthAnimation.fromValue = 0.9
    widthAnimation.toValue = 0.0
    widthAnimation.duration = 15
    widthAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut)
    return widthAnimation
}

/// animate the scale
func animateScale(toValue: CGFloat, duration: Double) -> CABasicAnimation {
    let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    scaleAnimation.fromValue = 1.0
    scaleAnimation.toValue = 12
    scaleAnimation.duration = 55
    scaleAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
    scaleAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    scaleAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .linear)
    return scaleAnimation
}
    
func pulsate(animationDuration: CGFloat) {
    var animationGroup: CAAnimationGroup!
    let newLayer = CALayer()
    animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    animationGroup.duration = CFTimeInterval(animationDuration)
    animationGroup.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    
    newLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
    newLayer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width/2
    newLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height/2)
    newLayer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width/2
    newLayer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7215686275, green: 0.5137254902, blue: 0.7647058824, alpha: 0.7).cgColor
    
        animationGroup.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut)
    animationGroup.animations = [animateScale(toValue: 7.5, duration: 2.0),
                                 animateBorderWidth(toValue: 0.6, duration: Double(animationDuration))]
        animationGroup.duration = 14
    newLayer.add(animationGroup, forKey: "pulse")
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width/2
    self.layer.insertSublayer(newLayer, at: 0)
}

func removeAnimation() {
    self.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeAnimation(forKey: "pulse") }
}
```

}
[image]

And add in UIViewCOntroller this animation to view

```
func startPul() {
self.backPulseView.pulsate(animationDuration: 2.0)
}
```

But if I press button I want to stop animation and hide
Im trying

```
func stopPul() {
self.backPulseView.removeAnimation()
}
```

But animation still working and dos't removed

How can I remove animation and then I can call again?

stop animation I call from button tap

```
 @IBAction func stopBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    stopPul()
 }
```

Comment: Check this for pause and resume animation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43909370/14733292

Comment: @RajaKishan did't help this pause function

Comment: Can you minimal example code? and GIF or video?

Comment: @RajaKishan add gif and function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the animation iterate through `sublayers` and remove animation for that "pulse" key:

```
self.layer.sublayers?.forEach {
            $0.speed = 0
            $0.removeAllAnimations()
            $0.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
}
```

Comment: I added below pulsate function and when I need to remove calling self.backPulseView.removeAnimation() and nothing happens

Comment: @Oleg Did you add `self.backPulseView.removeAnimation()` in `stopPul` ? When you are calling the stopPul method??

Comment: no, I change this I press button on view controller(where does the animation place) and call function func stopPul() {
        self.backPulseView.removeAnimation()
    }

Comment: Try self.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeAllAnimations() } and check if it works now.

Comment: delete animation but not stop(removes lines but draws new lines from)

Comment: @Oleg Could you try again with the updated one. It's working for me.